# Webpack not rewriting asset urls (stylus)

Tags: webpack, stylus, postcss

I am trying to rewrite my assets paths from a certain path (`~assets/myimage.png`) to the correct directory (in my case `/assets/`).

I told my webpack to write all images to a folder inside public. The images are correctly written, however the url in the build css is not adjusted accordingly.

This is the rule i am using for my stylus files

```
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  fallback: {
    loader: require.resolve("style-loader"),
    options: {
      hmr: false
    }
  },
  use: [
    {
      loader: require.resolve("css-loader")
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve("stylus-loader")
    }
  ]
})
```

and the one i am using for the assets

```
{
    test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
    loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
    options: {
      limit: 100,
      name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
    }
},
```

My alias that resolves to the correct directory:

```
assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public")
```

and the public path is set as `/assets/`

```
publicPath: publicPath + "assets/",
```

Since i use ExtractTextPlugin, the style loader can not be used. When using style loader only it works, however in my use case i need a css file as `/style.css`

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `file-loader` for images.

```
test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Gives me the same result as when using *url-loader*

Comment: Yes, it does the same, but it rewrites your URLs in CSS files. The best practice is to use `url-loader` for fonts, and `file-loader` for images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have tried using *file-loader* but it still doesn't rewrite my url path in the CSS file

Comment: What will you get, if you removed `assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public")` and `publicPath: publicPath + "assets/",` ?

Comment: i need that path for my service to handle the assets correctly

Answer (score 0):

Before passing your CSS to `file-loader`/`url-loader`, it might be necessary to **resolve relative assets urls**.

I never used `stylus-loader`, but I would try the trying approach as any other CSS preprocessor and use [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader):

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test   : /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader']
      }, {
        test   : /\.styl$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'stylus-loader?sourceMap']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Tried this, it didn't change anything

Comment: Can you provide the output of you css `url` paths? What file extension are using for your `stylus` files?

Comment: I managed to fix my issue. Apparently the styles were correctly generated before but my service was changing it unecessarily. The resolve-url-loader is still not necessary though. Thank you for time and help,

Answer (score 0):

It's just a thought, but might your alias be wrong? You wrote

```
assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public")
```

but regarding that your project structure looks something like this

```
--project_root/
 |--public
 |--src
 |--webpack.conf.js
```

it should be

```
assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "public") //without the "folder up" operator
```